# VBA code to change the selection of a drop down list (combo box)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I ran the macro recorder and changed the selection of a drop down list that is formatted with data validation, and nothing was recorded. Does this mean that there is no way in VBA to change the displayed selction of a drop down box? I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more detail. Is this drop down list made using data validation or as an active X control embedded into the sheet? What have you researched and tried so far? Do you have any VBA you are attempting to use? What version of Excel?

Comment: @CharlieRB edited

Comment: What have you tried already? So the recorder didn't catch anything, did you google if it was possible? (It is). What did you find?

Comment: @Raystafarian I googled a bunch and found details about changing the data validation, but didn't see anything about changing my selection.

Comment: To add to what @CharlieRB said, how are you doing this? With a button? Incorporated into other VBA? Etc..

Comment: @Raystafarian I just made a new spreadsheet with a combo box, referencing 3 cells for selections options "1","2","3", and tried recording a macro of me changing my selection. And no code was recorded.

Comment: What's the goal? What's the code for? Users to click a button? For a subroutine to change based on something else? This is very broad. [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240832(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: @Raystafarian I have a different spreadsheet where if the user clicks a button and a bunch of conditions exist it will change the drop-down selection to reflect visually that something happened in VBA.

Comment: Take a look at [Excel VBA Combo Box](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/combo-box.html).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it's super simple.
All you need to do is to change the number value of whatever you're using as your "Cell link," which you can easily do in VBA.

Comment: Great! It would be awesome if you took a few minutes to detail your answer so those who look to this in the future will have something more specific to follow.